# Spring.Social.Dropbox API doing a callback to C# when successfully authorised

Tags: c#, dropbox, spring.net

I am currently looking into adding dropbox to my c# software. I am using `spring.social` from https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-dropbox.

I have the following code to do the authentication

```
private void authenticateDropbox()
        {
            try
            {
                DropboxServiceProvider dropboxServiceProvider = new DropboxServiceProvider(dropboxAppKey, dropboxAppSecret, AccessLevel.AppFolder);
                //lblStatus.Content = "Getting request Token";

                OAuthToken oauthToken = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.FetchRequestTokenAsync(null, null).Result;
                //lblStatus.Content = "Request token retrieved";

                OAuth1Parameters parameters = new OAuth1Parameters();
                string authenticateUrl = dropboxServiceProvider.OAuthOperations.BuildAuthorizeUrl(oauthToken.Value, parameters);
                //lblStatus.Content = "Redirecting user for authentication";
                Process.Start(authenticateUrl);


            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("AggregateException: Failed to authenticate\n\n" + ex.Message, "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("General Exception: Failed to authenticate\n\n" + ex.Message, "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
```

I am successfully loading my default browser and I can allow the app and I get the success page. In the same after it has done the `Process.start()` method it asks the user to press enter to continue after the success page has been shown, however, I am doing it in a wpf application and I don't really want to have to ask the user to press a button to make my program continue after authorisation from the browser.

I saw in the `FetchRequestTokenAsync` function there is a callback parameter but I am not sure how to do this or even if this is what I want.

Basically what I want is when the browser says that authorisation was successful it closes the browser and C# picks up that it was successfully authorised and then continues.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.Start()` is used in the Console quick start, but if you are using a WPF application, you should use the `WebBrowser` control to load the authorization page.
Then register to the `Navigating` event to know when the success callback page is called.

Check the Windows Phone 7 quick start in the zip package, you can easily port it to WPF.
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-net-social-dropbox/tree/master/examples/Spring.WindowsPhoneQuickStart/Spring.WindowsPhoneQuickStart